# Why can I not print the result of my function?

Tags: python

How to display the value of `clazz`?

```
def k_nearest_neighbors(node, nodes, k=3):
    x1, y1 = node
    distances = []
    for x2, y2, node_cls in nodes:
        distance = abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2)
        distances.append((node_cls, distance))
        distances = sorted(distances, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)
        classes = [x[0] for x in distances[:k]]
        
cards = [
    (2, 0, "schilten"), (0, 1, "schilten"), (0, 2, "schilten"),
    (9, 2, "rosen"), (1, 13, "rosen"),
    (3, 3, "eichel"),
    (5, 5, "schellen"),
    
]
card = (2, 1)
clazz = k_nearest_neighbors(card, cards)
```

`print(clazz)` does not work.

Comment: *Why* it doesn't work?

Comment: What does `k_nearest_neighbors` return?

Comment: forgot the first row:
def k_nearest_neighbors(node, nodes, k=3):

Comment: @Gralsi you should [edit] the question to correct the code.

Comment: Since `k_nearest_neighbors` doesn't return anything, the value of `clazz` is `None`

Comment: But it should give schilten, rosen, eichel or schellen back. Is my code missing something for this?

Comment: Yes, a `return` statement (return = give something back). See link above.